# Renaming a function with args without rewriting them - Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, args, renaming

in my code I have a class and I need to get a function at

`this.behaviour.trembling.start(with many args...)`

and create a function in my class called

`startTrembling(with the same many args...)`

which simply calls the first function passing the args. Something like this:

```
startTrembling(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, ...) { 
this.behaviour.trembling.start(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, ...); }
```

The issue is that if I change an argument in the first function I also have to change it in the second one. I was just wondering if there is a way to simply rename the first function, using direclty its parameters.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `this.behaviour.trembling.start = startTrembling` will make both point at the same function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming you're not using arrow functions:**

*You can use spread operator over the implicit [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object*

```
function startTrembling() {
  this.behaviour.trembling.start(...arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object combined with the [`spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator:

Here, `arguments` will contain every argument from the parent function, all you have to do is `spread` those arguments.

```
startTrembling(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, ...) { 
    this.behaviour.trembling.start(...arguments); 
}
```